# I don't get all the product description data with Scrapy

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, scrapy

I am doing web scraping for learning purposes, I am even at a basic level of scraping. The next problem is that when I run the scraping the data obtained is little and the other data is null.

This is code:

### items.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define here the models for your scraped items
#
# See documentation in:
# https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html

import scrapy


class MercadolibreItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    #departamento = scrapy.Field()
    #precio = scrapy.Field()
    descripcion = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

### mercadolibreperu.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from mercadolibre.items import MercadolibreItem

class MercadolibreperuSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'mercadolibreperu'
    allowed_domains = ['mercadolibre.com.pe']
    start_urls = ['https://listado.mercadolibre.com.pe/lima/mascarilla-n95_ITEM*CONDITION_2230284']

    rules = (
        #Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'Items/'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                restrict_xpaths=(
                    '//section[@id="results-section"]',        
                ),
            ),
            callback='parse_item',
            follow=True
        ),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        #item = {}
        #item['domain_id'] = response.xpath('//input[@id="sid"]/@value').get()
        #item['name'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="name"]').get()
        #item['description'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="description"]').get()
        item = MercadolibreItem()
        item['descripcion'] = response.xpath('//h2[@class="item__title list-view-item-title"]/a/span/text()').get()
        return item
```

### Results obtained:  mercadolibre.json

```
[
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": " Mascarillas N95: 3m - 8210 Oferta!!! "},
{"descripcion": " Mascarillas N95 "},
{"descripcion": " Agotado Mascarillas N95 Sin Filtro "},
{"descripcion": " Mascarilla Steelpro M920v - N95 ( Caja De 10 Uni) Oferta "},
{"descripcion": " Mascarillas 3m 8511 N95 "},
{"descripcion": " Mascarillas N95 "},
{"descripcion": " Mascarillaa 3m N95 Por Unidad "},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": " Mascarilla N95 - 3m "},
{"descripcion": " Respirador N95 Normado Kimberly Clark (mascarilla) "},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": " Mascarillan95 "},
{"descripcion": " Mascarillas N95 Certificadas "},
{"descripcion": " Mascarilla N95 3m "},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": " Mascarilla N95 Segre Ffp2 "},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": " Mascarillas 3m N95 Modelo 8210 Certificada "},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": " Mascarilla N95 "},
{"descripcion": " Mascarillas N95 3m 1860 X Unidades A 43 Soles "},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": " Venta De Mascarilla 3m N95. "},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": " Mascarilla Respirador N95 X Unidad Gerson Equivale A 3m 8210 "},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": " Mascarilla 3m N95 1860 Originales S/.70 Unid.y 1100 Caja "},
{"descripcion": " Mascarilla Tipo N 95 C\u00f3nica Caja 50 Unidades "},
{"descripcion": " Mascarilla K N95 Selladas Y Certificada Ce, Fda. "},
{"descripcion": " Mascarilla D95 Selladas Original Tip N95 (entrega Inmediata) "},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": null},
{"descripcion": " Mascarilla 3m Respirador 8210 N95 Caja X 20 Unid Orginal "}
]
```

Please support me in seeing this problem. Cheers

Comment: first add urls to MercadolibreItem to check later in web browser if visited urls have data. Maybe  simply they don't have expected data.

Comment: BTW: for learning you could use http://toscrape.com/ created by Scrapy's authors. Some portals may have strong system to recognize bots/scripts and block them.

Comment: if page has many results then you may have to use `for`-loop to create separated `item` for every result and `yield item` (inside loop) instead of `return item` (after loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pages with results have many elements but using `.get()` you get only first element on page. You have to use `.getall()` with loop which `yield` every element in separated `MercadolibreItem()`

For tests I used normal dictionary instead of `MercadolibreItem()`

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    #item['domain_id'] = response.xpath('//input[@id="sid"]/@value').get()
    #item['name'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="name"]').get()
    #item['description'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="description"]').get()

    for element in response.xpath('//h2[@class="item__title list-view-item-title"]/a/span/text()').getall():
        item = {}
        #item = MercadolibreItem()
        item['descripcion'] = element
        yield item
```

But to get many values for every element it is better to find objects which keeps elements (without using `get()` or `getall()` and later use relative xpath (starting at dot `.`) to search name, description inside every evey object separatelly.

Searching first all names and later all descriptions you may get lists with different number of elements (if some of object has no name or description) and later it is problem to group name with description in correct pairs.

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    for element in response.xpath('//li[@class="results-item highlighted article stack item-without-installmets"]'):
        item = {}
        #item = MercadolibreItem()
        item['title'] = element.xpath('.//span[@class="main-title"]//text()').get()
        item['price_symbol'] = element.xpath('.//span[@class="price__symbol"]//text()').get()
        item['price_fraction'] = element.xpath('.//span[@class="price__fraction"]//text()').get()
        yield item
```

---

Minimal working code which you can put in single file and it doesn't need to create project

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
#from mercadolibre.items import MercadolibreItem

class MercadolibreperuSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'mercadolibreperu'
    allowed_domains = ['mercadolibre.com.pe']
    start_urls = ['https://listado.mercadolibre.com.pe/lima/mascarilla-n95_ITEM*CONDITION_2230284']

    rules = (
        #Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'Items/'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                restrict_xpaths=(
                    '//section[@id="results-section"]',        
                ),
            ),
            callback='parse_item',
            follow=True
        ),
    )

    def parse_item_old(self, response):
        #item['domain_id'] = response.xpath('//input[@id="sid"]/@value').get()
        #item['name'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="name"]').get()
        #item['description'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="description"]').get()
        for element in response.xpath('//h2[@class="item__title list-view-item-title"]/a/span/text()').getall():
            #item = {}
            item = MercadolibreItem()
            item['descripcion'] = element
            yield item

    def parse_item(self, response):
        #item['domain_id'] = response.xpath('//input[@id="sid"]/@value').get()
        #item['name'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="name"]').get()
        #item['description'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="description"]').get()

        for element in response.xpath('//li[@class="results-item highlighted article stack item-without-installmets"]'):
            item = {}
            #item = MercadolibreItem()
            item['title'] = element.xpath('.//span[@class="main-title"]//text()').get()
            item['price_symbol'] = element.xpath('.//span[@class="price__symbol"]//text()').get()
            item['price_fraction'] = element.xpath('.//span[@class="price__fraction"]//text()').get()
            yield item

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',

    # save in file CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',     # csv, json, xml
    'FEED_URI': 'output.csv', #
})
c.crawl(MercadolibreperuSpider)
c.start()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your support, it helped me a lot